# Elliptical Cone

Tags: geometry, mathematical-modeling, constructive-mathematics

I have a building design in the shape of an elliptical cone.
To understand the elevation of the structure. I need to draw/unfold an elliptical cone.
Can somebody explain the process for the same ?